# Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So in my effort to learn PHP I'm trying to make a basic pastebin script.

At the moment I've created a config file and the index.php. I need to echo the text of a table column.

I'm using the following.

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM paste_docs WHERE option_name = 'content'");
echo $stmt;
```

But of course that is throwing me an error.

The paste_docs table has two columns.
ID & Content

Side question: how would I get the last valid row ID and add +1 so when a paste submission is made it does not conflict?

Comment: Why don't you start from any tutorial?

Comment: Check out if ';' is missed or not. And i m very much late for reply. I had missed. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following

```
$stmt->execute();    

$result = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php
and http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: try var_dump($result); The type should indeed be an array and if you echo an array you see the array type.

Comment: thanks! How would I get it to display "Hello world" only?
array(1) { ["Content"]=> string(12) "Hello world!" }

Comment: echo $result['content'];

Comment: getting no result with that. Should I assign $result to the vardump output?

Comment: what is the name of your variable? $result?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35521/discussion-between-vernard-and-john)

Comment: $result at the moment just returns the query.

Comment: Continue this in the chat.